# How to Select a price with jQuery or Regex within a span?

Tags: jquery, html, regex

How to select the price value (here 79,90) within a span tag ?

```
<span name="data_udpade_minicard">2\&nbsp; article(s)<br>79,90 €</span>
```

- the string which is right *after* the `<br>`?
- or the string which is right *before* the "€" ?

I tried by stripping out the beggining with Regex:

```
$('span').text().replace(/.*article\(s\)/,"");
```

the result is

```
"2  79,90 €"
```

Comment: If it's your mark-up - why don't you just wrap the part you want in a `span`? It makes selecting it a lot cleaner.

Comment: If you are using this price for transaction, then this method is vulnerable. Anyone can inspect and will make this price to 0.

Comment: Guys, I have no control over the markup. Only access to JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var b =$($("span").children('br').get(0).nextSibling);
alert(b.text());
```

Comment: would you explain the first $ ?

Comment: Converted to jquery object , If you want to try without first $ then use b.wholeText